# How do I find out which application or which command was issued to logout a user?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, logout

I would like to locate the log file that stores which application or which command was issued to logout a user.

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 system that is behaving oddly. It logs out while I am in the midst of doing work. I would like to fix this issue.

The system is using this kernel `5.4.0-42-generic #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu`.

**Update:**

I found a group of error msgs using this command `cat /var/log/syslog.1 | grep ERROR`. Not sure if it is related to my issue.

```
Aug 16 19:53:53 Machine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2451]: mutter:ERROR:core/window.c:5332:get_default_window_icon: assertion failed: (default_icon)
Aug 16 19:54:07 Machine whoopsie-upload-all[9276]: ERROR: processing /var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: JS ERROR: Could not load extension ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com.bak: Error: uuid "ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com" from metadata.json does not match directory name "ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com.bak"#012createExtensionObject@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:135:15#012_loadExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:186:25#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012scanExtensions/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:197:13#012collectFromDatadirs@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/fileUtils.js:27:17#012scanExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:196:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_loadExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:330:5#012enableAllExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:338:9#012_sessionUpdated@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:369:9#012init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:377:5#012_initializeUI@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:229:5#012start@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:133:5#012@<main>:1:31
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine org.gnome.Shell.desktop[11079]: mutter:ERROR:core/window.c:5332:get_default_window_icon: assertion failed: (default_icon)
Aug 16 19:54:40 Machine whoopsie-upload-all[11118]: ERROR: processing /var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
Aug 16 19:54:47 Machine chromium-browser.desktop[27638]: [27638:27638:0816/195447.653920:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_x11.cc(63)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
Aug 16 19:54:47 Machine chromium-browser.desktop[27638]: [27671:27671:0816/195447.659608:ERROR:x11_util.cc(112)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

I also ran `cat /var/log/syslog.1 | grep gnome-shell` to see the gnome-shell msgs at the same time period. See below.

```
Aug 16 19:53:53 Machine gnome-shell[2451]: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
Aug 16 19:54:07 Machine whoopsie-upload-all[9276]: ERROR: processing /var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
Aug 16 19:54:07 Machine whoopsie-upload-all[9276]: Collecting info for /var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash...
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine dbus-daemon[1403]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service' requested by ':1.30034' (uid=1000 pid=11079 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: Some code accessed the property 'ScreencastIface' on the module 'screencast'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: JS WARNING: [~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com/extension.js 943]: reference to undefined property "MESSAGE_TRAY"
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: Some code accessed the property 'SoundDeviceChooserBase' on the module 'base'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: Some code accessed the property 'SETTINGS_SCHEMA' on the module 'prefs'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: JS WARNING: [~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/sound-output-device-chooser@kgshank.net/convenience.js 200]: reference to undefined property Symbol.toPrimitive
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: Some code accessed the property 'SHOW_INPUT_SLIDER' on the module 'prefs'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: [Dynamic Panel Transparency] Using theme data for: Sierra-light
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: loading user theme: /usr/share//themes/Sierra-light/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: Some code accessed the property 'NetSpeed' on the module 'net_speed'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: Some code accessed the property 'NetSpeedStatusIcon' on the module 'net_speed_status_icon'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: Some code accessed the property 'LayoutMenuItem' on the module 'layout_menu_item'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: JS WARNING: [~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/netspeed@hedayaty.gmail.com/net_speed_status_icon.js 157]: assignment to undeclared variable device
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: Device -> 
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: JS ERROR: Could not load extension ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com.bak: Error: uuid "ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com" from metadata.json does not match directory name "ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com.bak"#012createExtensionObject@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:135:15#012_loadExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:186:25#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012scanExtensions/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:197:13#012collectFromDatadirs@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/fileUtils.js:27:17#012scanExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:196:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_loadExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:330:5#012enableAllExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:338:9#012_sessionUpdated@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:369:9#012init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:377:5#012_initializeUI@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:229:5#012start@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:133:5#012@<main>:1:31
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: Extension dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com already installed in ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com will not be loaded
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: Extension drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com already installed in ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com will not be loaded
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: Extension user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com already installed in ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com will not be loaded
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: Extension workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com already installed in ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com will not be loaded
Aug 16 19:54:27 Machine gnome-shell[11079]: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
```

Aside from all the msgs relating to `property`, I noticed

`Machine gnome-shell[11079]: loading user theme: /usr/share//themes/Sierra-light/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`

The directory path appears to be wrong. I do not know if it is causing the issue. The theme does work. But the correct path should be `/usr/share/themes/Sierra-light/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`. How do I rectify this?

Comment: You could try `cat /var/log/syslog | grep shutdown` or yesterday's log might be syslog.1 or something similar

Comment: "Binary file (standard input) matches" O.o Looks like a system crash that wrote NULs to the log file.

Comment: @darth_epoxy. Thanks. I found in `syslog.1` ERROR around the time when my system rebooted . Also found other gnome-shell msgs at that time.

Comment: Good to hear. Please accept the answer (grey icon at LHS of Answer) so that this question can be considered answered. If you have specific challenges from what you have learned in the syslog then post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type `cat /var/log/syslog | grep shutdown` or yesterday's log might be syslog.1

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention these commands returned nothing. The issue is that the system had logout the user but did not automatically shut down. Manual shut down was performed sometime when the logout occurred, the system hung too.